# Cycles Bloom isn't working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

So I watched a few tutorials to create a glowing bloom effect around objects, but my object doesn't glow even though I copied everything.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure the compositor is set to `Always` or `Camera` in the viewport. Only then you will be able to see the compositor output in the viewport. Otherwise it will be visible only in the final render. 
   [image]
2. Try lowering the threshold in the glare node. The threshold decides which pixels gets the glare effect. Any thing lower than the threshold will not have the glare effect. It might be possible that your emmision strength is not strong enough to trigger it.